# Adding a payment method to .NET with Stripe

Tags: c#, .net, stripe-payments

I am working in .NET and trying to implement a subscription model to my website. However, I run into a problem when trying to add a payment method to a customer.

According to the official documentation ([see here](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/attach?lang=dotnet)) I should be able to do this by creating a payment service method, creating payment options, and attatching the payment id. My code looks like this, where I have verified that paymentID and customerID are both strings, and valid tokens:

```
var options = new PaymentMethodAttachOptions
{
  Customer = customerID,
};
var service = new PaymentMethodService();
service.Attach(paymentID, options);
```

However, when running this, I get the error
Stripe Error: A token may not be passed in as a PaymentMethod. Instead, create a PaymentMethod or convert your token to a PaymentMethod by setting the `card[token]` parameter to tok_1O31PJCcOIFUjYBMeREONJw8.

I tried modifying my code to create a payment method. So it now looks like this:

```
//Options
var options = new PaymentMethodAttachOptions
{
    Customer = stripeID,
};
//Service
var service = new PaymentMethodService();
//Payment method
var paymentMethod = await service.GetAsync(paymentMethodId);
//Attatch
await service.AttachAsync(paymentMethod, options);
```

As it suggested, I converted my token to a PaymentMethod and passed that as the parameter. However, this made my compiler complain because AttatchAsync expects a string, not an object.
Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: From the error, it looks like you need pass an object id. You should log these `paymentMethod` and `paymentMethodId` to see what are being returned. I think you'd want to pass in `paymentMethodId` instead of `paymentMethod` but I'm unsure without additional context.

Answer (score 1):

According to Stripe the recommended way to add a payment method without actually charging the customer is to use [SetupIntents](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/setupintents/lifecycle)
https://stripe.com/docs/api/setup_intents

For my SaaS product that uses Stripe for subscriptions I found it simpler, and just safer since I don't handle any customer payment information, to create [payment links](https://stripe.com/docs/payment-links/create) for each subscription. When the user clicks on the link they are directed to Stripe to checkout and then my webhooks just listen for the events that they checked out to enable their subscription.